# Inserting differntial data into postgresql table from db2 table trough trigger

Tags: postgresql, db2

I am looking the differential data load from db2 tables to PostgreSQL. Is there any free tool? or how I can write the trigger to connect two databases?

will db2_fdw in PostgreSQL will help me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write to nicknames in triggers in Db2.
You may use [SQL Replication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.repl.sqlrepl.doc/topics/iiyrscncsqlreplovu.html?cp=SSEPGG_11.5.0) to a federated data source (PostgreSQL in you case) depending on your Db2 version.
[11.5 Federation for PG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/tlsodb01type1.html)
[11.1 Federation for PG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/t0070302.html)

Comment: I am referring to do the same through  InfoSphere Federation Server and installed the latest version from IBM website, while running the executable iisetup.exe, federation tool create the db2 instances and ask for db2user password and port as well, I have given all the required information and at the end installation and JDBC wrapper was successfully completed. after that I have open the db2 command prompt through administration. I am getting issue in running all the command eg:

Comment: errors are: C:\db2\BIN>db2start
SQL1390C  The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid. C:\db2\BIN>db2 GET DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION
DB21018E  A system error occurred. The command line processor could not
continue processing.

Comment: All db2 commands should be run from the `Start -> Run -> db2cwadmin` command window (looks like ordinal CMD + setting necessary environment variables) and not from ordinal CMD.

Comment: Kindly Ignore above issue.. it got resolved. and please help me to resolve the below issue.                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931731/psqlexception-unexpected-error-code-55000-received-from-data-source-fedser