# PSQLEXCEPTION: Unexpected error code "55000" received from data source "FEDSER". Associated text and tokens are "This ResultSet is closed."

Tags: postgresql, db2

I am trying to do the differential data load from db2 to PostgreSQL table through InfoSphere Federation Server.

Followed below steps and got the expeption:

> SQL1822N  Unexpected error code "55000" received from data source "FEDSER". 
>   Associated text and tokens are "This ResultSet is closed.".

Please find the below steps which I followed:

```
create wrapper jdbc
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

CREATE SERVER FEDSER TYPE JDBC VERSION '12' WRAPPER JDBC OPTIONS( ADD DRIVER_PACKAGE 'E:\Sandhya\postgresql-8.1-415.jdbc3.jar', URL 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SCOPEDB', DRIVER_CLASS 'org.postgresql.Driver', DB2_IUD_ENABLE 'Y', db2_char_blankpadded_comparison 'Y', db2_varchar_blankpadded_comparison 'Y', VARCHAR_NO_TRAILING_BLANKS 'Y', JDBC_LOG 'Y')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR SANAGARW SERVER FEDSER OPTIONS (REMOTE_AUTHID 'postgres',REMOTE_PASSWORD '*****')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SCOPE".EMPLOYEE
SQL1822N  Unexpected error code "55000" received from data source "FEDSER". 
Associated text and tokens are "This ResultSet is closed.".
```

I am using Postgres version 12, Java version "1.8.0_241"

Please help me to  resolve this issue. or once connection get created then I can only create the nickname.

Comment: `postgresql-8.1-415.jdbc3.jar` - why are you using such an ancient, outdated and discontinued driver version? With Postgres 12 you should be using the current JDBC driver.

Comment: I have tried with upgraded JDBC jar and got the same exception..  db2 CREATE SERVER jdbc_ser TYPE JDBC VERSION 3.0 WRAPPER jdbc  OPTIONS (DRIVER_PACKAGE 'E:\Sandhya\postgresql-42.2.11.jar', DRIVER_CLASS 'org.postgresql.Driver',  URL 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SCOPEDB')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

Comment: using postgresql-42.2.11.jar also getting same error..

Comment: Look in the Db2 diagnostics file (e.g. db2diag.log) for more details. If necessary run `db2 update dbm cfg using diaglevel 4 immediate` (this makes Db2 diagnostics verbose and slows down Db2) and retry to see if you get more details from Db2. You should then revert to diaglevel 3 to keep the diagnostics file at a reasonable size.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Db2 11.5 instead of InfoSphere Federation Server which went out of support 2017-09-30 https://www.ibm.com/support/lifecycle/#/search?q=InfoSphere%20Federation%20Server

Db2 11.5 includes inbuilt support for PostgreSQL federation in all Db2 editions including Db2 Community Edition

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/data-source-support-matrix-federation-bundled-db2-luw-v115